# d3 change scale domain and keep the zoom working as expected

Tags: d3.js, zooming, scale, axis

I have a question about zoom and scale/axis.

At some point my chart has the following configuration:

Y domain scale:

```
this.scaleY = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .domain([10, 20])
  .range([this.chartHeight, 0]);
```

ZoomTransform:

```
{
  x: -10,
  y: -4,
  k: 0.2
}
```

now, I change programmatically the y-scale domain (and axis):

```
this.scaleY = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .domain([80, 100])
  .range([this.chartHeight, 0]);
```

The problem is that if I zoom in/out, the y-scale go back to the original one.

So I'd like to change the domain of one axis, and keep the zoom working as expected.

I hope I've made myself clear.

Do you see any solutions in order to keep the current zoom and simply update the axis? I don't want to reset my zoom to the Identity.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `d3.event.transform` object also contains other methods on its prototype such as `rescaleY()`.

`rescaleY(originalYScale)` will return a y scale whose domain has been altered to take account of the `d3.event.transform`'s current transform parameters.

Then you can update your y axis with this new scale using the `axis.scale()` setter method. And finally, you can update your axis element (`g` element) using the `call() method.

So, as shown in [Mike Bostock's zoom example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/db6b4335bf1662b413e7968910104f0f), your zoom callback may look like:

```
function zoomed() {
  view.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
  gX.call(xAxis.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleX(xScale)));
  gY.call(yAxis.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleY(yScale)));
}
```